# No sound input device

Tags: microphone

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 and I have no sound input device -- at least that's the message I get when I try to use the microphone.  **pavucontrol** doesn't show an input device,nor does **alsamixer** nor does the loudspeaker control icon on the taskbar (or whatever you call that bar at the bottom of the screen).  I haven't attempted to use the microphone for several months, though it did work at one time.  How can I install the correct input device?

The output of **arecord -l** is:

```
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC295 Analog [ALC295 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Further information:

1.The mic works fine in Win10 on the same machine.

2. Fiddling with **arecord** and **audacity**still fails.
3. A few months ago the mic worked; I haven't used it more recently.
4. I'd like to reinstall **alsa-base** but that would force reinstallation of **kubuntu-desktop**, and that seems dangerous.  I wonder if there are some configuration files I could remove that would be regenerated.
   `

Comment: Haven't actually used Kubuntu, but is there a Software & Updates application with a driver tab, or an Additional Drivers application, or something simalar? If there is a proprietary driver for it, you may have to install it.

Comment: This is tough. What is the output of `arecord -l`? Because pulse audio is based on Alsa. If Alsa doesn't know your device, pulse won't either.

Comment: The output of arecord -l is: card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC295 Analog [ALC295 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: Are you using a laptop? In that case, what model is?. Is not ideal but depending on the model if nothing else works you can buy a $10 USD USB mic + audio dongle. You can try to boot with an Ubuntu live just to check if it detects the sound card.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to have solved itself.  I tried logging as a different user and the microphone worked.  I tested it using the Skype echo test and also with Audacity.

For anyone else encountering a dead mic, see if the problem is still there when you log in as a different user.  Whether the mic is working or not, you'll exclude a whole lot of possible causes of the problem.

Comment: Paul, did you log in as root and start 'pulseaudio -D' ? In my case 'let's note' laptop, I logged in with root account, output-side of ALC295 Analog worked
but input-side of ALC295 Analog did not work.